# Spring SessionFactory Injection Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I've been trying to learn to use various featured of Spring 3.0.x and I've come across an issue when I'm trying to inject a session factory into a DAO implementation. I receive a NullPointerException when I try to use my injected SessionFactory instance variable which leads me to believe that the problem exists in the bean definition.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.timerecorder"/>

  <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx:xx"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**EntryImpl.java**

```
package com.timerecorder.entity;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EntryImpl implements EntryDao
{

  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Autowired
  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) 
  {
      this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean saveEntry(EntryForm efd) 
  {
      // Place the details from the entry form into the Entry entity
      Entry e = new Entry();
      e.setId(Long.valueOf(efd.getUserId()));

      this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(e);

      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean removeEntry(Long id) 
  {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public List getEntries(Long id) 
  {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public Entry getEntry(Long id) 
  {
      return new Entry();
  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Justin

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it may be a naming convention problem in your bean definations.

Try renaming

`id= "mySessionFactory"`

to

```
id= "sessionFactory"
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're autowiring by name but you need to autowire your sessionFactory by type instead - or you can rename the bean definition to sessionFactory and it should just work.

Also, you need to be sure you're getting your bean out of the application context instead of just new'ing it.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response however I've already tried this possibility and although it may be part of the issue it does not solve the overall problem.

Comment: Forgot to ask if you could elaborate on the second part of your response as I'm not following what I should do. Thanks again :-)

Comment: well, usually you'll do something like: ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/beans.xml"); and then when you want an instance of a bean you would then go context.getBean("entryImpl"); which will get the properly constructed bean out of the application context.

Comment: The technique Dataknife is suggesting above is not the recommended way to obtain Spring beans from the container. Using @Autowired is one correct approach according to IoC principles. The other approach just treats Spring like a big Factory and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try the method init() to autowire the session factory.

This is how it works for me ->

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory factory) {
        setSessionFactory(factory);
    }
}
```

setSessionFactory is the method provided by HibernateDaoSupport